# How to obtain a 'normal' boxplot? (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I was trying to make a boxplot using the R environment following the many guides that I found online (such this one: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) using my dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)


value=c('2000000','115000','500000','20000','3000','1000000')
condition=c('C','C','C','H','H','H')

df=data.frame(value,condition)
df$value=as.factor(df$value)

ggplot(df, aes(x=condition, y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

However, following these steps, my results is similar to this figure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HloKG.png

I can't figure it out why ggplot cannot understand that I'm using two conditions!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Why are your `value` values character (originally) or factor (after `as_factor`)?  They need to be numeric for a boxplot y axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)

ggplot(df, aes(x = condition, y = value))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute should be numerical, not a factor:

```
df$value=as.factor(df$value)
```

Then you will have two boxplots of condition type.